# determine whether the following sequence is convergent or divergent. Find the limit of the sequence if it is convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image: Q1 (a)]

determine whether the sequence is convergent or divergence. Find the limit of the sequence if it is convergent.  $$a_n=\frac{2^n}{n^2-2n+1}$$

Comment: can someone help me, is the answer i wrote for that question correct or no?

Comment: Well it's not correct.

Comment: please help me solve this problem

Comment: I can only give you a hint and then you have to finish it. Try to find the limit n tends to infinity |a_{n+1}/a_{n}| and show that it is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by the binomial expansion of $$2^n=(1+1)^n=1+n+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}+...,$$ we see that $$\frac{2^n}{n^2-2n+1}>\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)/6}{(n-1)^2}$$
$$=\frac{n(n-2)}{6(n-1)} $$ $$>\frac{n}{6}.\frac{1}{2}$$ $$=\frac{n}{12}\text { for }n>4.$$You can take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that $\displaystyle a_n=\frac{2^n}{n^2-2n+1}\approx \frac{2^n}{n^2}$ for $n$ big enough. Then study the convergence.